# How to show widgets (like cleanmaster & whatsapp) even when app is moved to SD card?

Tags: android, widget, storage, external

First of all widget of my app is not shown on widget list, then i found that the app must be in internal storage, then i moved my app to internal storage, only then the widget is showen on the list or launcher.

But

How Whatsapp, Clean master and others widgets are shown even when the app is moved to external storage?

Pls temme. Thanks in advance.